# How to move to the right the label Core Plot?

Tags: xcode, core-plot, padding

I use the following method to display the labels for my plot:

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{ 
 ... 
 CPTTextLayer *label=[[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:stringValue style:textStyle];
 }
```

which for every index should return the label

I know that it's possible to move label up or down using:

```
plot.labelOffset=10;
```

The question is: how can i move the label a bit to the right?
I tried to use

`label.paddingLeft=50.0f;`

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding padding as in your example does work, but maybe not in the way you expect. Scatter and bar plots will center the label above each data point (with a positive offset). The padding makes the whole label wider so when centered, the test appears off to the side. It's hard to control, especially if the label texts are different lengths.

There is an outstanding issue to address this ([issue 266](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=266)). No guarantees when it will be fixed, but it is something we're looking at.

Comment: Having the same problem. Want to displace the Label to the left.Is there any solution now??

Comment: Increase the `paddingRight` inside the label text layer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and came up with a different solution.

What I decided to do was to create the label using the CPTAxisLabel method initWithContentLayer:

```
CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:labelStr  style:axisTextStyle];

CGSize textSize = [textLayer sizeThatFits];

// Calculate the padding needed to center the label under the plot record.
textLayer.paddingLeft = barCenterLeftOffset - textSize.width/2.0;

CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithContentLayer:textLayer];
```

Here barCenterLeftOffset is the offset of the center of the plot record.

I wrote an article about this:

http://finalize.com/2014/09/18/horizontal-label-positioning-in-core-plot-and-other-miscellaneous-topics/

A demo project I created that uses this solution can be found at:

https://github.com/scottcarter/algorithms

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass CPTTextLayer and include an offset.

```
@interface WPTextLayer : CPTTextLayer

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint offset;

@end

@implementation WPTextLayer

-(void)setPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    CGPoint p = CGPointMake(position.x + self.offset.x, position.y + self.offset.y);
    [super setPosition:p];
}
```

Then Use:

```
WPTextLayer *tLayer = [[WPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"blah" style:textStyle];
tLayer.offset = CGPointMake(3, -3);
return tLayer;
```

There may be consequences of this that I'm not aware of, but it seems to be working so far.